# Rails STI add additional fields to childs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sti

I am having a parent class `User` from the [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 256 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 256 }

  def full_name
    first_name + ' ' + last_name
  end
end
```

And I want to have two types of accounts in my project, for example `Participant` and `Mentor`. As long as I've read, it is a good approach to use *single-table inheritance (STI)*, but my newly added fields do not appear in the models.

---

I have the following migration files:

```
class CreateParticipants < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :participants do |t|
      t.string :team_name
      t.references :mentor

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateMentors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :mentors do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Simply, I want to have a `Participant` model, where I have additional `team_name` field and also a *foreign-key relation to the `Mentor` model*.

`participant.rb`:

```
class Participant < User
  # _________________^
  validates :team_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }

  belongs_to :mentor
end
```

`mentor.rb`:

```
class Mentor < User
  # ____________^
  has_many :participants
end
```

But the newly added fields do not appear, although they appear in `db/schema.rb`.

Answer (score 4):

In STI, child models do not have a specific table in the database. All children share the parent table. You could define new methods and attributes in subclasses, but if you want to save then in the database, you must create these fields in the parent table. This is not a good option if you need many fields, as many of them could be empty (if the user is not a participant)

If you need to save more information on children, you can use other approach, such as polymorphic associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html (chapter 2.9)